# Recycle Item Click issue and never go into function

Tags: android, onclick, adapter, android-recyclerview

I'm new on Android material design and wanna use Recycle View instead of List View but having problem on implement OnClickListener.
I find out that RecyclerView.Adapter a bit different from ListView.Adapter.
first I impelement OnClick listener in `onBindViewHolder` but it returns wrong item numbers and lead to out of-bound after some removing.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
 final int index = i ;
personViewHolder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
    ...           items.get(index).gettext();
    }
```

so I find out that I should implement OnClikListener in my ViewHolder class as this [link](https://gist.github.com/grantland/cd70814fe4ac369e3e92).

but in this case never inter to OnClick.

```
 public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.i("log","position="+getAdapterPosition());

    }
}

 public CardViewAdapter(List<MessageTO> persons) {
        this.items = persons;
    }


@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.deposite_card_view, viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
...
}
```

also I find out that I should do my Initializing item values all in `onBindViewHolder` is it right or not? I am very confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: @random I check that. it's not happening.

Comment: I see that you're using `PersonViewHolder` in onBindViewHolder. But you're checking `onClick` in a `ViewHolder` class. Please see that you're adding `onClick` to correct view holder class that is used in your recycler view

Comment: @random I copy paste the link code in second part. Ok I will update question

Comment: Also post your `onCreateViewHolder` and what elements you have in your view holder and what are you clicking

Comment: @random ok, I updated the question.

Comment: follow this it has everything you need for recycler view http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set the onclicklistener as shown below. Then it should work.

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        .
        .
        .
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Log.i("log","position="+getAdapterPosition());

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(viewHolder)` somewhere to make it work

Comment: You implement the onClickListener but never attach it to the viewHolder view itself.

Comment: when it's implements an event it not need to asigning.

Comment: You're wrong. You need to assign the OnClickListener to some sort of view to make it works. In the link that you provided it is attached in viewholder constructor (public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            mTextView = (TextView) view;
        }) , but there is no assignment in your code.